# Regex to extract names from HTML

Tags: python, html, regex

I have two pieces of code below from which I want to extract the names.

Code:

```
 ;"><strong>DeanSkyShadow</strong>
 ;"><strong><em>Xavier</em></strong>
```

The regex should extract the names *DeanSkyShadow* and *Xavier*. My current regex:

```
(?<=(;"><strong><em>)|(;"><strong>))[\s\S]+?(?=(</em></strong>)|(</strong>))
```

grabs the names correctly if there is no em tag in the code; if there is then it also grabs the opening em tag, like this: `<em>Xavier`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions where a HTML parser would be much better suited?

Comment: Well because i have no idea what an HTML parser is, could you explain more? I am using urllib2 to first read the html of a specific page then using a regex to extract names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match anything that is *not* a `<` character; you also cannot use a variable-width look-behind so your version doesn't work at all. Use a non-capturing pattern instead

```
(?:;"><strong>(?:<em>)?)([^<]+?)(?=(?:</em>)?</strong>)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
...  ;"><strong>DeanSkyShadow</strong>
...  ;"><strong><em>Xavier</em></strong>
... '''
>>> re.findall(r'(?:;"><strong>(?:<em>)?)([^<]+?)(?=(?:</em>)?</strong>)', sample)
['DeanSkyShadow', 'Xavier']
```

The *better* solution is to use a HTML parser instead. I can recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

for strong in soup.find_all('strong'):
    print strong.text
```

Comment: Nice, a better solution indeed.

Comment: thanks for the regex update, it works now :) was confused before